# RealVNC Viewer and Tor

Tags: socks, proxy

I want acess my server over VNC, cause RealVNC only client with proxy support under windows, I choosed it.
But when I setup proxy, socks5 with 127.0.0.1:9150 in RealVNC,  It requesting username and password ! 
For example any other program over tor proxy not requesting password (I tried putty, chrome browser).
Tor settinngs - default, nothing changed.
 But what default username and password for tor socks proxy ?

Comment: Tor doesn't require a username or password. Does it mean the name and password for the VNC server you're trying to connect to?

Comment: no, realVNC requiring password for tor as socks proxy server !

Comment: can you post your torrc config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor utilises the SOCKS username and password authentication mechanism for isolation, not access control. You can enter any credentials and it will accept them as valid.

I'd be wary of adding the `PreferSOCKSNoAuth` option to the `SOCKSPort` config because this might mislead some applications into *not* using it for circuit isolation where they're configured to (Tor Browser, how would Firefox's SOCKS implementation handle this?). Instead set some arbitrary login for it like "realvnc:realvnc". This will have the added benefit of your VNC traffic using a distinct circuit that won't be potentially linked to your other Tor traffic.

Comment: yes, any login:password also providing authentication. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this solving by adding option `PreferSOCKSNoAuth` to tor config file `torrc-defaults`.

```
SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth PreferSOCKSNoAuth
```